# Get URL parameters with a dot ( . ) in the middle of the name using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, url-parameters

I have a url with parameters like:

```
exampleurl.com\info?color.id=12345&name.id=6789
```

I'm using AngularJS '$location' to get the parameters from the URL.

```
var color = $location.search().color.id;
var name = $location.search().name.id;
```

This is getting an error because it cannot read the .id property of undefined, which I knew would happen.

My question is though, how can I get the color.id and name.id values from the parameters?

Comment: Does it work if you do `var color = $location.search()['color.id'];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var color = $location.search()['color.id'];
```